# Creating JSON in a class in Python

Tags: python, json

I need to create a JSON class base called `JCarOwner`. It has to get attributes from its owner such as name, manufacture and year. I want to make it an unknown attribute:

```
def add_co (existing owner name, new_attribute , attribute content)
```

But I don't really know how. This is my code (corrected):

```
import json

class JCarOwner:

    CarOwner = []

    def __init__(self,name,manufacture=None,production_year=None):
        super(JCarOwner, self).__init__()
        self.CarOwner.append(json.dumps({"Owner_Name": name, "Car_Manufacture": manufacture, "Production_Year": production_year}))

    def COsave(filename):
        JCarOwner.CarOwner.dumps(filename,separators=(',', ':'))

    def COload(filename):
        JCarOwner.CarOwner.append(json.load(filename))

    def DispInfo(Car_Owner):

        for owner in JCarOwner.CarOwner:

            CO = json.load(owner)
            if CO[owner]["Owner_Name"]==Car_Owner:
                print(CO[owner])


jane = JCarOwner("Jane","Mazda",2016)
bob = JCarOwner("bob")     

JCarOwner.DispInfo(jane)
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: What is a "json class" ?

Comment: just a class compose of json file in a list

Comment: And what is an "unknown attribute"?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman something that the user want to add, if the json file had only name and car so the new will be price.

Comment: `json` is a text format (like say csv, xml, yaml etc), so the term "json class" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers change it. I just want to creat a list of json files in a class that add save and load json files.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Do you get an error? What have you tried already?

Comment: @Steve I tried adding :jane = JCarOwner("Jane","Mazda",2016) and got this: 
AttributeError: type object 'CarOwner' has no attribute 'append'

Comment: This sounds like the type of info you should edit in to your question :)

Comment: @Marcy just did.

Comment: You should include the stack trace also, so we can see whats triggering the error

Comment: @Craicerjack what's a stack trace?

Comment: The stack trace is the whole error. It gives information about the error. What triggered it, all the way back to what causes it. Its the information around your `AttributeError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self.CarOwner` instead of plain `CarOwner`.

```
 def __init__(self,name,manufacture,production_year):
   super(JCarOwner, self).__init__()

   self.CarOwner.append(json.dumps({"Owner_Name": name, "Car_Manufacture": manufacture, "Production_Year": production_year}))
```

Please try to follow certain python conventions.

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters

Comment: Sorry my bad. fixed it.

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: which json library are you using? I'm assuming you are just importing default python json library. Try using 'json.loads' instead of 'json.load'.

Comment: I am using default Jason and tried loads and got: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'.

Comment: Oops. I just copied your line of code. Anyway my bad, 'json.dumps' is for creating json string, while `json.loads` is for reverse operation. Check my updated answer.

Comment: it works tnx! I have another follow-up Q, if I want to add an owner name without a car, what should I change? I want it to be fluid.. add any new attribute..

Comment: what do you mean by "owner name without a car"?

Comment: instead of this line: jane = JCarOwner("Jane","Mazda",2016) I want to add this bob= JCarOwner("bob")

Comment: Then I'm guessing other params are optional. `def __init__(self, name, manufacture=None, production_year=None)` should to the job.

Comment: if I want to print the json by name how can I do this:   def DispInfo(Car_Owner)?

Comment: use `json.loads`

Comment: used that but got an error, check out my correct code in the Q.

Comment: `json.loads` not `json.load`.

Comment: corrected it and still got: 
KeyError: '{"Owner_Name": "Jane", "Car_Manufacture": "Mazda", "Production_Year": 2016}'